# How to show that $ \lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{-2}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{4-x^2}}{(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})-x}e^{-(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})t}\,dx $？

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Why the following limit of the integral about $x\in [-2,2]$ is zero? For $\lambda>0$,

$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{-2}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{4-x^2}}{(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})-x}e^{-(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})t}\,dx=0?
$$

It is clear that $(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})-x>0$ as $x\in [-2,2]$.

Comment: I don't think this result is true since $$
\int_{-2}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{4-x^2}}{(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})-x}e^{-(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})}dx\ge \int_{1}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{4-x^2}}{(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})-x}e^{-(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})}dx \to\infty
$$ when $t\to\infty$.

Comment: @xpaul Sorry, I miss $t$ in $e^{-(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})t}$.

Comment: What is your $t$?

Comment: @Hermi I assume $\lambda \gt 0$ and $\lambda \neq 1$ based on your statement of "$(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})-x>0$ as $x\in [-2,2]$". Regardless, please update your question to make this clear. Also, if so, then your integral has an upper bound of the form $c_1e^{-c_2t}$ for a constant $c_1 \gt 0$ and $c_2 = \lambda + \frac{1}{\lambda} - 2 \gt 0$. Thus, as $t \to \infty$, this upper bound goes to $0$ so, by the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), your limit is $0$. However, for $\lambda = 1$, I'm not offhand sure what the limit would be, or if it even exists.

Comment: Yes. $\lambda>0$. But why there will a problem for $\lambda=1$?

Comment: @Hermi At $\lambda=1$, we have $\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda}=2$. Note for $x \neq 2$ that $\frac{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{2 - x} = \frac{\sqrt{2 - x}\sqrt{2 + x}}{\sqrt{2 - x}\sqrt{2 - x}} = \frac{\sqrt{2 + x}}{\sqrt{2 - x}}$. Thus, the integrand approaches $\infty$ as $x$ approaches $2$. Nonetheless, the integral does exist. Letting $y=2−x$, we have $\frac{\sqrt{2 + x}}{\sqrt{2 - x}} = \frac{\sqrt{4 - y}}{\sqrt{y}}$. For $0 \lt y \le 4$, we have $\frac{\sqrt{4 - y}}{\sqrt{y}} \le \frac{2}{\sqrt{y}}$, for which the integral is $4\sqrt{y}$, which means the integration exists going from $0$ to $4$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan How about Sangchul Lee's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $\alpha=\lambda+\lambda^{-1}$ and noting that $\alpha \geq 2$, the integral is recast as

$$ \int_{-2}^{2} \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\alpha - x} e^{-(\alpha-x)t} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

For $t \geq 0$ and $-2 < x < 2$, we find that

$$ 0 \leq \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\alpha - x} e^{-(\alpha-x)t} \leq \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2 - x} = \sqrt{\frac{2+x}{2-x}}. $$

Since this bound is integrable over $(-2 ,2)$, we may apply the dominated convergence theorem to get

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \biggl( \int_{-2}^{2} \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\alpha - x} e^{-(\alpha-x)t} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr)
= \int_{-2}^{2} \biggl(\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{\alpha - x} e^{-(\alpha-x)t} \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x
= 0. $$

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda \ne 1$, we have
$$\int_{-2}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{4-x^2}}{(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})-x}e^{-(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})t}\,dx
\le \int_{-2}^2\frac{e^{2t}\sqrt{4-0^2}}{(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})- 2}e^{-(\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda})t}\,dx.$$

If $\lambda = 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-2}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2-x}e^{-2t}\,dx
 &= \int_{-2}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{2+x}}{\sqrt{2-x}}e^{-2t}\,dx\\
 &= \int_{-2}^{2 - 1/t}\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{2+x}}{\sqrt{2-x}}e^{-2t}\,dx
 + \int_{2-1/t}^2\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{2+x}}{\sqrt{2-x}}e^{-2t}\,dx\\
 &\le \int_{-2}^{2 - 1/t}\frac{e^{xt}\sqrt{2+2}}{\sqrt{2-(2-1/t)}}e^{-2t}\,dx
 + \int_{2-1/t}^2\frac{e^{2t}\sqrt{2+2}}{\sqrt{2-x}}e^{-2t}\,dx\\
 &= 2\sqrt{t}\, e^{-2t}\cdot \frac{e^{2t-1} - e^{-2t}}{t} + \frac{4}{\sqrt t}.
\end{align*}

Then use the squeeze theorem to obtain the desired result.